# Do one webservice request only from play framework

Tags: json, scala, web-services, playframework, future

I'm new to the play framework generally and how to use it with Scala. I want to build a proxy for big Json objects. I achieved so far that the json is stored in a cache and if it is not there, requested from a webservice.

However when two requests are coming in, targeting the same end point (webservice and path are identicall) only one call should be performed and the other request should wait for the result of the first call. At the moment it is performing a call to the service with every request.

This is my controller:

```
@Singleton
class CmsProxyController @Inject()(val cmsService: CmsProxyService) extends Controller {
  implicit def ec : ExecutionContext =  play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.defaultContext

  def header(path: String) = Action.async { context =>
    cmsService.head(path) map { title =>
      Ok(Json.obj("title" -> title))
    }
  }

  def teaser(path: String) = Action.async { context =>
    cmsService.teaser(path) map { res =>
      Ok(res).as(ContentTypes.JSON)
    }
  }
}
```

This is the service:

```
trait CmsProxyService {
  def head(path: String): Future[String]

  def teaser(path: String): Future[String]
}

@Singleton
class DefaultCmsProxyService @Inject()(cache: CacheApi, cmsCaller:  CmsCaller) extends CmsProxyService {

  private val BASE = "http://foo.com"
  private val CMS = "bar/rest/"

  private val log = Logger("application")

  override def head(path: String) = { 
    query(url(path), "$.payload[0].title")
  }

  override def teaser(path: String) = {
    query(url(path), "$.payload[0].content.teaserText")
  }

  private def url(path: String) = s"${BASE}/${CMS}/${path}"

  private def query(url: String, jsonPath: String): Future[String] = {
    val key = s"${url}?${jsonPath}"
    val payload = findInCache(key)

    if (payload.isDefined) {
      log.debug("found payload in cache")
      Future.successful(payload.get)
    } else {
      val queried = parse(fetch(url)) map { json =>
        JSONPath.query(jsonPath, json).as[String]
      }
      queried.onComplete(value => saveInCache(key, value.get))
      queried
    }
  }

  private def parse(fetched: Future[String]): Future[JsValue] = {
    fetched map { jsonString =>
      Json.parse(jsonString)
    }
  }

  //retrieve the requested value from the cache or from ws
  private def fetch(url: String): Future[String] = {
    val body = findInCache(url)

    if (body.isDefined) {
      log.debug("found body in cache")
      Future.successful(body.get)
    } else {
      cmsCaller.call(url)
    }
  }

  private def findInCache(key: String): Option[String] = cache.get(key)

  private def saveInCache(key: String, value: String, duration: FiniteDuration = 5.minutes) = cache.set(key, value, 5.minutes)

}
```

And finally the call to the webservice:

```
trait CmsCaller {
  def call(url: String): Future[String]
}

@Singleton
class DefaultCmsCaller @Inject()(wsClient: WSClient) extends CmsCaller {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  //keep those futures which are currently requested
  private val calls: Map[String, Future[String]] = TrieMap()

  private val log = Logger("application")

  override def call(url: String): Future[String] = {
    if(calls.contains(url)) {
      Future.successful("ok")
    }else {
      val f = doCall(url)
      calls put(url, f)
      f
    }
  }

  //do the final call
  private def doCall(url: String): Future[String] = {
    val request = ws(url)
    val response = request.get()
    val mapped = mapResponse(response)
    mapped.onComplete(_ => cmsCalls.remove(url))
    mapped
  }

  private def ws(url: String): WSRequest = wsClient.url(url)

  //currently executed with every request
  private def mapResponse(f: Future[WSResponse]): Future[String] = {
    f.onComplete(_ => log.debug("call completed"))
    f map {res =>
      val status = res.status
      log.debug(s"ws called, response status: ${status}")
      if (status == 200) {
        res.body
      } else {
        ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: How can only one call to the webservice beeing executed? Even if there are several requests to the same target. I don't want to block it, the other request (not sure if I use the right word here) shall just be informed that there is already a webservice call on the way.

The request to head and teaser, see controller, shall perform only one call to the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer using Scala lazy keyword**

```
def requestPayload(): String = ??? //do something

@Singleton
class SimpleCache @Inject() () {
  lazy val result: Future[String] = requestPayload()
}

//Usage

@Singleton
class SomeController @Inject() (simpleCache: SimpleCache) {
  def action = Action { req =>
   simpleCache.result.map { result =>
     Ok("success")
   }
  }
}
```

First request will trigger the rest call and all the other requests will use the cached result. Use map and flatMap to chain the requests.

**Complicated answer using Actors**

Use Actor to queue requests and Cache the result of the first successful request json result. All the other requests will read the result of the first request.

```
case class Request(value: String)

class RequestManager extends Actor {

  var mayBeResult: Option[String] = None
  var reqs = List.empty[(ActorRef, Request)]

  def receive = {
    case req: Request => 
     context become firstReq
     self ! req
  }

  def firstReq = {
    case req: Request =>
     process(req).onSuccess { value =>
       mayBeResult = Some(value)
       context become done
       self ! "clear_pending_reqs"
     }
    context become processing
  }

  def processing = {
    case req: Request =>
    //queue requests
    reqs = reqs ++ List(sender -> req)
  }

  def done = {
   case "clear_pending_reqs" => 
     reqs.foreach { case (sender, _) =>
       //send value to the sender
       sender ! value.
     }
  }
}
```

handle the case where the first request fails. In the above code block if the first request fails then actor will never go to the done state.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However I'm still having difficulties understand. Where does the process(req).onSuccess comes from? Is that the actual call to my service, which I need to implement?

Comment: @Spindizzy Provided simple solution using lazy val. Have a look

Comment: I followed the Actor approach and got it running. However it is still calling several times. There is another service in front, which uses the controller. It seems like the number of calls (wsClient) is bound to the number of requests. So I guess there is no solution. I just have to accept it.

Comment: @Spindizzy Cache the first request result and all the other similar requests can use the first request result. Note that this is sound only if you are requesting same thing again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with a synchronization of the cache in the service. I'm not sure if this an elegant solution, but it works for me.

```
trait SyncCmsProxyService {
  def head(path: String): String
  def teaser(path: String): String
}


@Singleton
class DefaultSyncCmsProxyService @Inject()(implicit cache: CacheApi, wsClient: WSClient) extends SyncCmsProxyService with UrlBuilder with CacheAccessor{

  private val log = Logger("application")

  override def head(path: String) = {
    log.debug("looking for head ...")
    query(url(path), "$.payload[0].title")
  }

  override def teaser(path: String) = {
    log.debug("looking for teaser ...")
    query(url(path), "$.payload[0].content.teaserText")
  }

  private def query(url: String, jsonPath: String) = {
    val key = s"${url}?${jsonPath}"
    val payload = findInCache(key)

    if (payload.isDefined) {
      payload.get
    }else{
      val json = Json.parse(body(url))
      val queried = JSONPath.query(jsonPath, json).as[String]
      saveInCache(key, queried)
    }
  }

  private def body(url: String) = {
    cache.synchronized {
      val body = findInCache(url)
      if (body.isDefined) {
        log.debug("found body in cache")
        body.get
      } else {
        saveInCache(url, doCall(url))
      }
   }
 }

 private def doCall(url : String): String = {
   import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
   log.debug("calling...")
   val req = wsClient.url(url).get()
   val f = req map { res =>
     val status = res.status
     log.debug(s"endpoint called! response status: ${status}")
     if (status == 200) {
       res.body
     } else {
       ""
     }
   }
   Await.result(f, 15.seconds)
  }
}
```

Note that I omitted the traits UrlBuilder and CacheAccessor here because they are trivial.